# Create a matrix with no decimals

Tags: matlab, matrix

I need create a matrix with no floating point values in MATLAB. For example I have created the following matrix `a`:

```
a = 

    1.0000         0         0         0   25.0000
    1.0000         0    1.0000         0   50.0000
    1.0000         0         0    1.0000   50.0000
         0         0         0         0   50.0000
         0         0         0         0   50.0000
         0    1.0000    1.0000         0   83.3333
```

But I would like the following matrix:

```
a =

    1         0         0         0        25
    1         0         1         0        50
    1         0         0         1        50
    0         0         0         0        50
    0         0         0         0        50
    0         1         1         0        83
```

Comment: And you've tried rounding off?

Comment: Do you want the data actually stored as integers or just displayed as integers?

Comment: i want to data stored as integer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To change the value, use the function `floor` `ceil` or `round`. To change the data type, use `int32` or similar.